# Fatal error with New Smarty() in phpMailer function

Tags: php, smarty, phpmailer

I have an inherited site and has been working just fine after a migration to a new hosting site and upgrade to newer Smarty 2.6.3 and PHP 5.6. Today I was doing some testing after some user complaints they weren't getting emails from the site (member registrations).

Started getting this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Smarty` today. Investigation showed that there are two `$temp = new Smarty()` statements in the system - one that is called when a user logs in setting up Smarty, and the second in class `Emailer` that uses `phpmailer`.

If I try to reference the initial Smarty setup variable, I get `call to null` errors. If I remove the smarty code in the emailer, email doesn't even get called. As I said, been working fine for a couple of years... No changes to the code in the past month...

Here's the smarty initialization in both modules:

```
// Setup.php
require('../Smarty-2.6.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$_TEMP = new Smarty();

class Emailer {...
require('../Smarty-2.6.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$temp = new Smarty();

...}
```

The need for Smarty in the emailer function is to use a Smarty template for the body of the email.

Comment: Realized I should have mentioned that the need for Smarty in the emailer function is to use a Smarty template for the body of the email.

Comment: The code above, is from a single file?

Comment: Sorry - no. the second one is in a separate class file that sets up the emailing function (cEmailer.php). The setup.php is called by the index.php code. the cEmailer is called by the various modules that send emails.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple thing - your problem is not that you're creating two Smarty instances, but that you're calling `require` on the same file twice. Do this instead:

```
// Setup.php
require_once('../Smarty-2.6.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$_TEMP = new Smarty();

class Emailer {...
require_once('../Smarty-2.6.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$temp = new Smarty();
```

That will solve your fatal error, however, you may now have a different error related to the fact that your creation of two instances my not be what you need, but that is a separate question.

While I'm here, *why* are you using the ancient Smarty 2.x? 3.x is far better.

Comment: I'm using the old smarty because this is an inherited site, and I'm just learning Smarty and some other libraries included in the code. Not ready to deal with the results of upgrading yet. Got enough problems upgrading from older versions of php and mysql.

Comment: And, it WORKS! Thank you very much!